# is it ok to say "it is an unfolded box"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request

> [unfold](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/unfold?q=unfold) [transitive, intransitive] unfold (something) to spread open or flat
>   something that has previously been folded; to become open and flat
>
> to unfold a map
>
> She unfolded her arms.

---

Say you have just bought a phone that was packed into a box. You then try to make the box spread open as the below picture:

[image]

Now, My little child asked me "**what is it**"?

I answered "**it is an unfolded box**"

is it ok to say "**it is an unfolded box**"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't *wrong*. "Unfolded" is the opposite of folded though - do you fold the card to put it back into a box?

I would probably call it a *flattened* box. In fact, when cardboard boxes are sold in this form they are usually called *flat boxes* or *flat-packed boxes*.

Comment: I would generally use flattened for a box crushed flat. I would probably say "un-assembled", "disassembled"  or even "box that was taken apart".

Comment: If you performed the action "unfold" on X, it's fair to say it's *unfolded*.  If it was shipped to you in that way, it hasn't been unfolded so *flattened* in that case is better.